# MPQ4470 12V to 5V, 3A output is not simulating as expected in SIMPLIS

Tags: power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, simulation, buck

I am new to SIMPLIS, simulating this [IC](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MPQ4470A/document_id/3860/) for converting 12 V to 5 V.

My first SIMPLIS circuit diagram is given below. My input is 12 V and the required output is 5 V. The load will take a maximum current of 3 A.

[image]

The output obtained after running the transient simulation is given below.

[image]

My simulation setting is given below.

[image]

ILOAD spec is given below.

[image]

May I know where I went wrong?

As [Rohat Kılıç](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/103420/rohat-k%c4%b1l%c4%b1%c3%a7) suggested, I increased the simulation time. Now the output is clamping to 4.5 V.

[image]

Spec of the inductor and capacitor is given below.

[image]
[image]

Output after running the simulation for 2s.

[image]

Comment: Define the parasitic parameters of the choke and the output capacitor. Those resistances will bring some damping on the start-up ringing. Also, from the datasheet, I can see that it takes a few milliseconds for the output to rise and reach the target value. Increase the simulation stop time to 10 ms and see if the output reaches 5V.

Comment: @RohatKılıç,edited the question as per your comments .could you please check

Comment: C4 is an interesting modification. With a time constant just below 1 s: what is the output voltage after 3 seconds?

Comment: @greybeard,May I know why

Comment: I assume C4 to be equivalent to a short way below R1C4, and R1 to open way above - *but not before*. (*If* this turns out relevant, there should be a caveat regarding *power good*.) It may (greatly) reduce "settle time" to start C4 at \$V_{out} - V_{ref}\$.

Comment: 2mR for 10uH/5A (or 10A) choke doesn't seem to be practical. Increase it to 10mR, or even 20mR. Don't leave output capacitor without ESR, so put something meaningful (5mR to 500mR). And see if they have any impact.

Comment: @RohatKılıç,tried all the things suggested by you,no change.I did not see any option for changing the esr of Ceramic Caps

Comment: @Hari, what voltage do you measure on FB pin? Does it come to 0.815V?

Comment: @Hari, one more question: does the output reach 5V if you have a very small load current of say 100mA?

Comment: @sai,Vfb is 800mV

Comment: @sai,output is not reaching to 5V for 100mA also ,it is stuck at 4.5V,the same circuit is giving proper 5V in the board :) ,my intention is to check the stability using simplis but simplis is not even giving proper output

Comment: @greybeard,"4 is an interesting modification. With a time constant just below 1 s".May I know  for calculating time constant wrt C4 which resistor I need to consider.After 3S output is coming to 4.9V

Comment: (I mentioned R1 above in the time constant `R1C`. I think the datasheet should mention that with the capacitor and resistor ranges suggested it takes on the order of one second for the output to come closer than 5 % low.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I agree with greybeard's point in the comments section. If you are getting 0.8V on FB, you have to get 4.9V at the output. Since you are not getting 4.9V, for sure, the entire current flowing in RFB (50uA) is not flowing in RFT. There must be some current flowing via C4. If you wait for long enough time, this current will die down and you will get 4.9V at the output. That is why on your PCB, it works because you allow several seconds before measuring the output.

Comment: ,You are correct.When I run the simulation for 1S,I am getting 4.9V.May I know any way to improve the response time

Comment: (@Hari The way to avoid this annoying settling time is to use the "external ramp circuit" from figure 11 of the datasheet. (I think your R1C3 on the low side: suggest checking.) (I have *no* idea why they should suggest Cdc/your C4 higher than, say, 10 to 20 times "the ramp capacitor"/their C4/your C3.))

Comment: @greybeard,"I think your R1C3 on the low side",May I know you mean I need to increase the value of R1 and C3

Comment: (@Hari: I think you should revisit what design documentation is available, starting with equations (4) to (6) from the datasheet, and (11). (I can't connect the dots eveywhere. (Why is R4&SW shown grounded? Why is it useful to assume \$I_{FB}\$ negligible against \$I_{C4}\$? Why would reducing C4 *increase* stability when it was introduced to establish stability in the first place?)))